# Automatic profile load on boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, login, fast-user-switching

Is there any way to configure a computer to login automatically at bootup and then IMMEDIATELY switch users? The purpose is to trigger the profile loading process for the assumed user so that when they go to login, their profile loads instantaneously. Yet, the immediate user switch means that the login password is still required before any actual use.

A few of the attempts I have made require storing the password in plain-text for the system to use. Needless to say that is undesireable.

I have been looking for this solution for years; if anyone knows of a better solution to skinning this cat I am all ears.

EDIT:
`tsdiscon` command will Lock the workstation.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure Windows to auto-login as the user, and then add a .bat file to lock the computer to that profile's startup queue:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

This will result in the profile returning to the password screen whenever it is loaded. If Windows loads it on startup, then it'll be forced back to the lock screen, but will still load  all of the profile-specific stuff in the background.

(My solution to this problem on the other hand is just to never reboot my computer)

Comment: Nice solution. One that I was considering. However is there any way to prioritize the .bat file? When I threw it in the Startup folder I could still get a few clicks off and such before things were locked down. I would like to minimize the chance of mischeif during this process.

Comment: On another note, the interwebs are awash with horror stories of that particular command causing mayhem in the stack.

Comment: It's kind of a moot point. If I can click the mouse, then I can also reboot the computer with a live CD and clear the password on the account. If you have someone sitting there, waiting for those few seconds to click on things, then this isn't the solution. I'm expecting this to be for having the computer automatically turn on in the morning, or something to that effect.

Comment: Touché. I will attempt to implement this tonight. I don't suppose there are any workarounds dodging the need for admin rights that you know about?